# Java String memory usage on Android platform

Tags: java, android, performance, memory

An Android/Java, suppose I have a really large string representing an image or video and we want to pre-pend a short string to the front of the large string, what's the most memory efficient way to achieve the new string?  It seems like some string operations could double the amount of memory being used.

```
 String finalResult = shortString + largeString;
```

Comment: Use `StringBuilder` instead of concatening Strings.

Comment: Your large string is going to be your memory killer, assuming that string is going to be a base64 string of an image there really isnt much you can do aside from not using a base64 string image since it has to load it all into memory. What are you trying to do with the large string?

Comment: Processing image data in memory, that's why I want the string ops to limit memory usage.  I understand the consequences of doing image data in memory, looking for an answer to the question and not a response of just don't do that.